# margin-bottom not working on a div containing three floating div

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Grid of Boxes</h2>
<p>Float boxes side by side:</p>

<div class="big-box" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
  <div class="box" style="background-color:#bbb">
  <p>Some text inside the box.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color:#ccc">
  <p>Some text inside the box.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color:#ddd">
  <p>Some text inside the box.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<p style="clear:both;">Note that we also use the clearfix hack to take care of the layout flow, and that add the box-sizing property to make sure that the box doesn't break due to extra padding. Try to remove this code to see the effect.</p>
```

in the above code `margin-bottom:30px` on `div` with `class = big-box` is not working.WHY???
I also need suggestions how can I apply margin bottom in this kind of scenerio.
I am very new to CSS and this might be a very silly questions or code may contain some silly errors.

Comment: wrap the paragraph in a `<div>your p tag here ....</div>` and see the change

Comment: overflow:auto on the big-box

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

1. Your big-box's margin bottom is working, but 30px is still small compare to the 3 floating boxes. So when you look at it, it does not look like the big box is wrapping the 3 boxes.

There are 2 solution:

1. specify a height that is bigger or at least equal to the 3 floating box.
2. remove float:left from your box class and give big box display:flex and 100% width

Below example is the second solution.

```css
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      .box{
        width:33.33%;
        padding:50px;
      }
      .big-box{
        display:flex;
        margin-bottom:30px;
        width:100%;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Grid of Boxes</h2>
    <p>Float boxes side by side:</p>

    <div class="big-box" >
      <div class="box" style="background-color:#bbb">
        <p>Some text inside the box.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box" style="background-color:#ccc">
        <p>Some text inside the box.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box" style="background-color:#ddd">
        <p>Some text inside the box.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p style="clear:both;">
      Note that we also use the clearfix hack to take care of the layout flow,
      and that add the box-sizing property to make sure that the box doesn't
      break due to extra padding. Try to remove this code to see the effect.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hopefully this is the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding height attribute value to your style. Without height it is normally assumed as a small space or line. So simply saying without it, when you are specifying the margin-bottom the text overlaps inside the boxes and html5 without any explicit declaration won't allow this. Try adding a border color you will understand what I am saying.
`<div class='big-box' style='height: somevalue; margin-bottom:30px; border: 2px solid red;' >`

Probably this will solve your issue and also you can add height to your box class too

Comment: no this will not solve the problem because as already correctly mentioned the problem is the float value. adding a height to the boxes will make the design unresponsive and still not fix the problem. you dont ever had and never will need a fixed height to sue a margin value.